# React CSSTransition with Route renders next page first then works with rendering next page again

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions, react-router-v4, reactcsstransitiongroup, react-transition-group

Starting from the state of that `Products` is rendered.

I want `Products` above to exit with animation and `ProductDetailPhotos` to appear when clicking `NavLink to={'/product-detail/' + variant.id}` which exists in `Products` view , however, firstly `Products` above is replaced by new `ProductDetailPhotos` and new another `ProductDetailPhotos` appear after it.

```
<TransitionGroup component="main" className="page-main">
  <CSSTransition key={location.pathname} timeout={timeout} classNames="fade" appear>
    <Switch location={location}>
      <Route exact path={'/'} component={ () =>
        <Products
          productsArray={this.state.myProductsArray}
          client={this.props.client}
        />
      }/>
      <Route path='/product-detail/:variantId' render={props =>
        <ProductDetailPhotos
          products={this.state.products}
          client={this.props.client}
          addVariantToCart={this.addVariantToCart}
          {...props}
        />
      }/>
      <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
    </Switch>
  </CSSTransition>
</TransitionGroup>
```

I explain actual by time series as below:

1. `Products DOM` is rendered
2. Click NavLink to /product-detail
3. `Products DOM` changes to `ProductDetailPhotos 1 DOM` with fade-exit classes immediately then `ProductDetailPhotos 2 DOM` with fade-appear classes is rendered
4. `ProductDetailPhotos 1 DOM` and `ProductDetailPhotos 2 DOM` start animation by CSS. `ProductDetailPhotos 1 DOM` animates to exit and `ProductDetailPhotos 2 DOM` does to enter.
5. `ProductDetailPhotos 1 DOM` finally disappear

My Expectation is below:

1. `Products DOM` is rendered
2. Click NavLink to /product-detail
3. `ProductDetailPhotos DOM` is rendered first with fade-appear classes
4. Then `Products DOM` starts animating to exit by CSS with fade-exit classes and `ProductDetailPhotos DOM` too with fade-appear classes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved by myself. Transform this:

```
<Switch location={location}>
```

into this:

```
<Switch key={location.pathname} location={this.props.location}>
```